# restrict-pointer-type template arguments and overriding virtual methods of a templated base class

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions, restrict-qualifier, template-classes

The following should, I believe, compile and link, but doesn't:

```
template<class S>
class A {
public:
    virtual int foo(S arg) = 0;
    virtual ~A() { }
};

class B : public A<int* __restrict__>
{
public:
    int foo(int* __restrict__  arg) override { return 0; }
};

int main() { B b; }
```

The compiler output:

```
d9.cpp:11:6: error: ‘int B::foo(int*)’ marked override, but does not override
  int foo(int* __restrict__  arg) override { return 0; }
      ^
d9.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
d9.cpp:14:16: error: cannot declare variable ‘b’ to be of abstract type ‘B’
 int main() { B b; }
                ^
d9.cpp:8:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘B’:
 class B : public A<int* __restrict__>
       ^
d9.cpp:4:14: note:  int A<S>::foo(S) [with S = int* __restrict__]
  virtual int foo(S arg) = 0;
```

If I remove the `__restrict__` qualifier in both places, it does compile and link.  What am I doing wrong?

**Notes:**

- This is the *only question* on SO (as of the time of writing) regarding both the restrict qualifier and templates. Funny, isn't it?
- I'm using GCC 4.9.3 with `--std=c++11`.

Comment: What is the compilers error?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Expecting compiler extention bringing features from another language to flawlesly integrate with C++specific features

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: But `restrict` is very important... it's not an obscure nice-to-have feature.

Comment: @tahsmith: See edit.

Comment: @einpoklum it doesn't matter how it is important. It is non-standard (yet). Most compilers have own limited and incompatible implementation. GCC explicitely states that it brough C99 restrict. This means that it is valid everywhere it would be valid in C (and explicitely as member function qualifier). Function overloading and templates are not from C and nowhere in documentaion is said that restrict is supported in such cases.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: Fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__restrict__` keyword does not seem to really create a new type:

> As with all outermost parameter qualifiers, `__restrict__` is ignored in
>   function definition matching. This means you only need to specify
>   `__restrict__` in a function definition, rather than in a function prototype as well.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html

Removing `__restrict__` in the template parameter and the pure virtual function definition while leaving it in the function definition itself seems to achieve what you want, though.